# Copying WeChat Sight Videos from S4

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, file-management, wechat

I use the [WeChat messenging application](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tencent.mm) on my Samsung Galaxy S4 Black Edition (GT-I9515). Among its features, users can send short videos as so-called *Sights*.

**I am trying to copy these videos to my PC.**

I have found some hints that ultimately have not helped me yet:

- `/tencent/MicroMsg/WeChat/` contains JPEG images of all the photos sent via WeChat messages, but no according video files for the video messages.
- [This website](http://www.softwarert.com/save-wechat-sight-videos/#save-wechat-sight-video-android) claims that videos are saved as MP4 files in the path `mnt/extSdCard/Tencent/MicroMsg` if an SD card is installed, but doesn't say anything about phones where no additional SD card has been installed (like mine). Evidently, the videos must still be saved somewhere, as I can access them without a network connection. Moreover, the website says "It varies depending on the phone model you use.", which makes me suspect my question is specific to S4s (and maybe a few other models), rather than generic for all Android uses of WeChat (hence the [samsung-galaxy-s4](/questions/tagged/samsung-galaxy-s4) tag).

  - Even so, after installing an additional SD card, WeChat apparently keeps saving any recorded or received data to the internal memory. There is no `Tencent` subdirectory in `mnt/extSdCard`, as far as I can tell.
- `/tencent/MicroMsg/*long number*/video/` seems to contain JPEG thumbnails of the videos, but not the videos themselves.

Comment: Have you checked all these locations *viz.* `/data/data/com.tencent.mm`, `/sdcard/data/com.tencent.mm/`, `/sdcard/tencent/`, `/sdcard/Tencent/`?

Comment: @Firelord: What is *viz*? In any case, there is no directory `data` or `sdcard` in the root directory of my phone.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of what you consider the root directory of the phone? Every Android has the directory `data` under `/` but now I assume your device is not rooted.

Comment: @Firelord: By *root directory*, I was referring to what I was seeing when looking at the phone contents in Windows Explorer after connecting it via USB as a "camera". It contains folders such as `Alarms`, `Android`, `Application`, and `DCIM`. I now see AndroXplorer apparently shows some more levels, including a `data` directory, but it appears to be empty. `/sdcard/data/` and `/sdcard/Tencent/` do not exist, `/sdcard/tencent/` looks exactly like the `/tencent/` directory I can access via Windows Explorer. I have, however, found an additional trace there (edited into the question). ...

Comment: ... No, my device is not rooted.